# Split string after every five words

Tags: php, preg-split

I want to split a string after every five words.

**Example**

> There is something to type here. This is an example text

**Output**

```
There is something to type
here. This is an example
text
```

How can this be done using `preg_split()`? Or is there any way to wrap text in PHP GD?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression too

```
$str = 'There is something to type here. This is an example text';
echo preg_replace( '~((?:\S*?\s){5})~', "$1\n", $str );
```

> There is something to type
>   here. This is an example 
>  text

Answer (score 4):

Here's my attempt at this, although I didn't use `preg_spilt()`

```
<?php
$string_to_split='There is something to type here. This is an example text';
$stringexploded=explode(" ",$string_to_split);
$string_five=array_chunk($stringexploded,5); 

for ($x=0;$x<count($string_five);$x++){
    echo implode(" ",$string_five[$x]);
    echo '<br />';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple algorithm would be to split the string on all spaces to produce an array of words. Then you could simply loop over the array and write a new line every 5th item. You really don't need anything fancier than that. Use [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to get the array.

Comment: Can be also used with `array_chunk`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: You can also use explode() on the string using spaces and continue using the technique described above. PHP's great for having lots of ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Although not hard to modify this, it doesn't fulfill the example posted, which has newline characters.

Comment: @chris: Only the output has new lines which are mentioned in my answer. The example input is a single line. Also, the original post mentioned splitting on spaces only. The updated post is less specific.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` and `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flags for [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
<?php
$string = preg_split("/([^\s]*\s+[^\s]*\s+[^\s]*\s+[^\s]*\s+[^\s]*)\s+/", $string, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

### Result

```
array (
  1 => 'There is something to type',
  2 => 'here. This is an example',
  3 => 'text',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function limit_words ($text, $max_words) {
    $split = preg_split('/(\s+)/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    array_unshift($split,"");
    unset($split[0]);
    $truncated = '';
    $j=1;
    $k=0;
    $a=array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($split); $i += 2) {
       $truncated .= $split[$i].$split[$i+1];
        if($j % 5 == 0){
            $a[$k]= $truncated;
            $truncated='';
            $k++;
            $j=0;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    return($a);
}
$text="There is something to type here. This is an example text";

print_r(limit_words($text, 5));



Array
(
    [0] => There is something to type
    [1] =>  here. This is an example
)
```