# Splits a string into an array with limitations

Tags: php

I want to Splits a paragraph into an array with words limitation!
For example this is the text:

```
$text =Lorem ipsum dolor! sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente nesciunt saepe ullam vitae corrupti quasi a nostrum in dolor minus?
```

I want to store 3 words in array( the length doesn't matter). this hould be something like this

```
$array = ['Lorem ipsum dolor!', 'sit amet consectetur', 'adipisicing elit. Sapiente']
```

I tried `preg_split` but he problem was I could not set the limitation for this case

```
preg_split('/\s+\W+/', $text);
```

Comment: Try using `explode()` to make an array of words, `array_chunk()` to group them in 3 words, then `implode()` each of the nested arrays.

Comment: Related: (Split string after every five words)[https://stackoverflow.com/q/10555698/2943403]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Barmars suggestion explode the string using each word, then chunk them into groups of three words with `array_chunk()`, this will create sub arrays with each word as an individual array => `Array ( [0] => Lorem [1] => ipsum [2] => dolor! ) [1] => Array ( [0] => sit [1] => amet [2] => consectetur ), etc...`Then implode that using space inside a foreach loop. I used a break tag to output each line.

```php
$text = explode(" ","Lorem ipsum dolor! sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente nesciunt saepe ullam vitae corrupti quasi a nostrum in dolor minus?");
$newArray = array_chunk($text, 3);
$output = null;
foreach($newArray as $line){
  $output .= implode(" ",$line)."<br>";
}
```

OUTPUTS:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor!
sit amet consectetur
adipisicing elit. Sapiente
nesciunt saepe ullam
vitae corrupti quasi
a nostrum in
dolor minus?
```

OR you could push them back into an array formatted with three words per value like so:

```php
$output = array();
foreach($newArray as $line){
  $output[] .= implode(" ",$line);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```php
print_r($output);

Array ( [0] => Lorem ipsum dolor! [1] => sit amet consectetur [2] => adipisicing elit. Sapiente [3] => nesciunt saepe ullam [4] => vitae corrupti quasi [5] => a nostrum in [6] => dolor minus? )
```